# HTML - Website looks correct in IE but bugs in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

You can find the website [here](http://artotek.fi).

On Chrome:
The icons jump some pixels randomly when you hover over them,
the languages bar is way too low...

On IE:
Looks and works correctly.

Here's only the most important of the CSS

### CSS:

```
#main
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#varjo {
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px gray;
}

.panel
{
    position: relative;
}

/* Me */

    #me
    {
    }

        #me .pic
        {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            border-left: 1px #E1E1E1 solid;
        }

            /*
                The pseudo element below applies a noise pattern to the "me" image. It's
                meant to help mask blurriness, but you can remove it if you don't like it.
            */



            #me .pic:before
            {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background: url('images/overlay.png');
                width: 100%;
                opacity: 0.5;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 1;
            }

    #lang
{
background: black;
opacity: 0.7;
width: 95%;
font-family: Poiret One;
transition: 0.5s opacity;
cursor: default;
position: fixed:
}

::selection {
color: green;
}

#lang:hover{
opacity: 1;
}

    #lang a
    {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
        width: 1em;
        width: 10%;
        height: 1em;
        line-height: 0.9em;
        margin-right: 150px;
        transition: 0.2s color;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

    #lang a:hover {
    color: lightgreen;
    }

        #lang a.icon:before
        {
            padding-right: 0;
        }
#nav
{
margin-top: 20px;
}

    #nav a
    {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
        line-height: 0.9em;
    }

        #nav a.icon:before
        {
            padding-right: 0;
        }

    .fa
{
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

    .fa.solo
    {
    }

        .fa.solo span
        {
            display: none;
        }

    .fa:before
    {
        display:inline-block;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    }
```

You can see the HTML in the Source Code :)

### Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

### IE:

[image: IE]

I think I'm using the most recent version of both, IE and Chrome.
Please help, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the vertical-align of your content is causing that...

### 1920 X 1080 Screen - Chrome

[image]

### 1280 X 800 Screen - Chrome

[image]

As you can see depending on the screen's size the spacing will change - (take a look for your scroll bar)

You can also add some `margin-top:` in your `#nav` element.
Something like:

```
#nav {
   margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Other important change on your site is that you have set `opacity: 0` in your `#nav .fa-film span`. Opacity 0 allows to show when you're hovering (and I guess that you only need to show that tooltip when user hover the icons). It's more useful set that span as `display: none` and then change your `#nav a:hover span` to

```
#nav a:hover span {
  display: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Can't see valign anywhere. Did you mean the tag or... Also what can I do to fix this? And what's with the icons?

Comment: Got the #lang fixed, but the icons still jump pixels :s

Comment: What is that mean, still jump pixels?

Comment: When I hover over the icons, they actually move (theirselves and a few other icons + plus some letters in content) left or right for a few pixels. Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: In what browser did you tested? I test in Google Chrome and it looks ok (none of icons already moves).

Comment: On my Chrome, hovering over the icons even move the image on the second page by a few pixels...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42984/discussion-between-francisco-carvalho-and-user109899)

Answer (score -1):

Add `body {margin:0px; padding:0px;}` to your CSS